# Apache Tomcat and Httpd - Sharing common web publication folder - CentOS

Tags: permissions, users, apache-httpd, tomcat, shared-folders

Suppose:

The `Httpd`'s Web publication folder is assigned according:

Edit `/usr/local/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` file:

```
  DocumentRoot "/usr/local/WebFiles/Html"
  <Directory "/usr/local/WebFiles/Html">
```

The `Tomcat`'s Web publication folder is assigned according:

Edit `/usr/local/tomcat/conf/server.xml` file:

```
  <Host name="localhost" appBase="/usr/local/WebFiles"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
  <Context path="" docBase="Html"
        reloadable="true" />
```

---

**Question 1:**

Is it possible share the Web publication folder between Tomcat and Httpd (or to use the same)?

---

Tomcat has the *group* and *user* named `tomcat`.

Httpd has the *group* and *user* named `apache`.

**Question 2:**

How the permission for both users (`tomcat` and `apache`) must be established for `/usr/local/WebFiles/Html` folder and files?

Answer (score 0):

if you mean /usr/local/WebFiles/Html by the publication folder in that case I'd say yes and the answer of the question two :
Create a group where you add tomcat and apache and grant this new group to read and execute the publication folder.

Comment: are you thinking in `chgrp` or `chown :groups`?

Comment: Thank you... About the first Question: I want to put files  handled by Apache `httpd` and Apache `tomcat` together!!!